# Python code for hailstone nums to check if the numbers are converging or not & also to findout how many diff holding pattern the sequence converges to

Tags: python

Recall in class that we discussed the hailstone numbers where xn = 3xn−1 +1 if xn−1 is odd and xn = xn−1/2 ifxn−1 iseven. Thehailstonenumbersconvergetoasortofholdingpattern4→2→1→4→2→1→ 4 → 2 → 1. We call this kind of pattern a convergence because it repeats.
Write a program to test generalized hailstone numbers where xn = axn−1 + b if xn−1 is odd and xn = xn−1/2 if xn−1 is even where a and b are positive integers. For each of the a, b pairs less than or equal to 10, find whether or not the sequence seems to converge. Once you can do that, tell me how many different holding patternsthesequenceconvergesto. Forinstance,whena=3andb=5then1→8→4→2→1this is holding pattern. However, if we start with a different number, say 5 we get a different holding pattern 5 → 20 → 10 → 5.

```
def validation(x,a,b):
    steps = 1
    start = x
    set1 = set()
    while x not in set1:
        steps += 1
        set1.add(x)
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x = x//2 
        else:
            x = a*x + b 
        if steps == 100: 
           break;
    if x == start:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def hailstone(number):
    List = []
    for i in range(1,11):
        for j in range(1,11):
            count = 0
            for x in range(1, number+1):
                if (((i%2 != 0 ) and (j%2 == 0)) or ((i%2 == 0 ) and (j%2 != 0))): 
                    break
                else:
                    if validation(x,i,j): #calling 'validation' to check if it is true 
                       count += 1
        
            List.append([i,j,count])
      
    return(List)

pattern_count = hailstone(number = 100)
print(pattern_count)
```

Comment: I used the code above but i am not sure if its right or wrong

Comment: One problem in `validation` is the test `if x == start` at the end. This will only detect a cycle if it happens to land exactly at the starting number. Suppose it started at 8. The loop would exit when it reached the 4->2->1 cycle, and since none of those are 8, it would incorrectly return false. If any number is seen more than once, then it has entered a cycle and needs to return true.